# Clicking a button on my Access subform moves to the next record

Tags: vba, ms-access

So I have a main form which contains a submit button. The user inputs the information, then clicks the submit button to save their changes. This submit button also marks the start time the moment it is clicked. On my subform, there is a button on the footer I have which upon a click marks the end time, then greys out until a new record is created. My main problem is that once this button is clicked, the end time is marked for a new record instead of the current record. Below is my code for on click:

```
Private Sub Command28_Click()
txtEndTime = Time()
Command28.Enabled = False
End Sub
```

Here is my code for the form's on current event:

```
Private Sub Form_Current()
    Me!Command28.Enabled = Me.NewRecord
End Sub
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated

EDIT: My code for the submit button:

```
Private Sub Command119_Click()
    If MsgBox("Do you want to save your changes?", vbInformation + vbYesNo) = vbNo Then
        TempSaveRecord = False
    Else
        TempSaveRecord = True
        [Start Time] = Time()
    End If
End Sub
```

My code for the main form's before update:

```
Private Sub Form_BeforeUpdate(Cancel As Integer)
    If (TempSaveRecord) Then
        DoCmd.Save
    Else
        DoCmd.RunCommand acCmdUndo
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to save the record:

```vb
Private Sub Command28_Click()
    Me!txtEndTime.Value = Time
    ' Save record.
    Me.Dirty = False
    Me!Command28.Enabled = False
End Sub


Private Sub Form_Current()
    Me!Command28.Enabled = Me.NewRecord
    If Me.NewRecord Then
        ' Clear textbox.
        Me!txtEndTime.Value = Null
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi Gustav, thank you for your response. Using this code gives me the same problem, however now I realize that before clicking the submit button, the end time marks in the correct record. I will paste my code for the submit button.

Comment: Perhaps the textbox is unbound. Then clear it - see extended answer, please.

Comment: Okay, so now the subform is showing two record fields in one record. The end time is displaying in the first field, as I wanted, but the other information is displaying on the next, so now it's basically the same problem, but in the opposite fields.

Comment: I must admit, that I'm lost. I can't figure out your scenario.

Comment: Okay no worries thank you for the help